# Show instance strange behaviour

Tags: haskell

I try, for training, create data structure same as Data.Tree:

```
data MyTree a = Tree a [MyTree a]
```

But I have a trouble when I try to create show instance for this data structure:

```
instance Show (MyTree a) where
  show (Tree a [v]) = show a -- Only first element
```

I get an error

```
No instance for (Show a)
arising from a use of `show'
```

It is some strange for me. As I can glance function *show* is able to work with any types.

And the second question: In the [standart library](http://darcs.haskell.org/ghc-6.6/packages/base/Data/Tree.hs) used *deriving* method, but there are some strange 
defenitions:

```
instance Eq a => Eq (Tree a)
instance Read a => Read (Tree a)
instance Show a => Show (Tree a)
instance Data a => Data (Tree a)
```

What does these means?

Comment: There's another probable bug lurking in this instance: the pattern `[v]` matches only a one-element list, and so `Tree a [v]` will fail to match, for instance, `Tree 0 []` and `Tree 2 [Tree 1 [], Tree 0 []]`.  Just use `v` to match anything (it's simply a variable), or `_` if you don't care about the value (`_` is a wildcard—it matches like a variable, but can't be referred to later).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Show` can be derived for any type, but if you want to use the derived version, you have to let the compiler know.

In order for your definition `show (Tree a [v]) = show a` to work, `a` must be an instance of `Show`. It could be a derived instance, or a custom instance. So we just need to tell the compiler that `a` is an instance of `Show`, like this.

```
instance (Show a) => Show (MyTree a) where
  show (Tree a [v]) = show a -- Only first element
```

A declaration such as `instance Eq a => Eq (Tree a)` says "As long as `a` is an instance of `Eq`, so is `Tree a`.